# Flask Application 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: flask, post, get

I have this weird error where I try to log into my flask application, but somehow, I always get a "405 Method not allowed".

My app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from models import db
from models import User, Score

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "super secret key"

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

db.init_app(app)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('userName')
        password = request.form.get('userPassword')
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user and user.password == password:
            flash('Login successful', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('game'))
        else:
            flash('Invalid username or password', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('userName')
        password = request.form.get('userPassword')

        existing_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if existing_user:
            flash('Username already exists', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            new_user = User(username=username, password=password)
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Registration successful', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('game'))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))



@app.route('/game')
def game():
    return render_template('game.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Space Invaders Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="mx-auto" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post">
        <h4 class="text-center" id="loginTitle">Login</h4>
        <div class="mb-3 mt-5">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" id="userName" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        </di
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="userPassword" id="userPassword">
            <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text mt-3">Forgot password?</div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5" id="submitButton">Login</button>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified mb-3" id="ex1" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="tab-login" data-mdb-toggle="pill" href="#pills-login" role="tab"
                  aria-controls="pills-login" aria-selected="true">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <a class="nav-link" id="tab-register" data-mdb-toggle="pill" href="#pills-register" role="tab"
                  aria-controls="pills-register" aria-selected="false">Register</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>


<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My script.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const loginTitle = document.getElementById('loginTitle');
    const emailHelp = document.getElementById('emailHelp');
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    const pills = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
    const loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');

    document.getElementById('tab-login').click();

    pills.forEach(pill => {
        pill.addEventListener("click", function () {
            pills.forEach(p => p.classList.remove("active"));
            this.classList.add("active");
            
            if (this.id === "tab-login") {
                loginTitle.textContent = 'Login';
                emailHelp.hidden = false;
                submitButton.textContent = 'Login';
                loginForm.action = '/login';
            } else if (this.id === "tab-register") {
                loginTitle.textContent = 'New Account';
                emailHelp.hidden = true;
                submitButton.textContent = 'Register';
                loginForm.action = '/register';
            }

        });
    });

});
```

When I start the application and load my webpage, whenever I click on the submitButton, I get the 405 error. However, when I switch my pills to "tab-register", the submit button works fine. Also, when I first click on "tab-register" and then click back on "tab-login", I can click the submitButton and it works just fine.

What exactly am I doing wrong in my code to create this error?